# Where can I find a compact/ultra 7 speed freewheel?

Tags: freewheel, vintage

Does anyone still make these?

I'm aware that I could coldset my frame for a wider spacing, but I'm interested to know if it's still possible to buy a compact freewheel (apart from via e-bay or another 2nd hand route).

Comment: Presumably you have friction shifting, so why not just go with a regular 6 speed freewheel? (I'm almost sure nobody makes 7 speed ultra/compact ones anymore and you're going to have to look on ebay or some second hand stuff, but a 6 speed will fit in the space)

Comment: @Batman because I'd quite like to have an extra granny gear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a few sources by searching on "compact 7-speed freewheel" – here is what [Sheldon Brown / Harris Cyclery](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/harris/freewheels.html#7) has. The claim is that they will work, perhaps with the addition of a thin washer or two if the clearance is tight around your dropouts. The appear to have new (or maybe NOS) [Sunrace FW760](http://harriscyclery.net/itemdetails.cfm?ID=1134) (13-25), and [Shimano FW722](http://harriscyclery.net/itemdetails.cfm?ID=2694) (13-28), and a [FW723](http://harriscyclery.net/itemdetails.cfm?ID=778) (14-34) freewheels in stock.

[Nashbar](http://www.nashbar.com/reviews/nashbar/power/pwr/product-reviews/Bike-Parts/Freewheels-Cassettes/Freewheels/Nashbar/p/NS__FW7-Nashbar-7-Speed-Freewheel.html) has a 13-24 and a 13-32. It appears that Amazon has some sellers with some as well.

[Hillary Stone](http://hilarystone.com/freewheels7_8spd.html) in the UK also has some, both NOS and used.

Comment: Thanks. Can't comment for the others on the Harris site, but I've tried a FW723 and it is not the same as an ultra - I got it going with a lot of washers and a super thin lock nut on the other end, but wasn't too happy with the arrangement. The nashbar looks interesting - but couldn't see anything on the site that explicitly states it is a compact.

Answer (score 0):

I am professional bike rider in Spain. As of my knowledge you can find it in UK or Spain. Because there are large cycling market and there is all parts available.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.   As someone from the antipodes, I know that the UK and Spain are both rather large.  Could you please edit your answer to provide some more specific info, like a URL or something to help narrow down the search?   And do remember that if you have any association with the subject of your answer then we require you to declare that connection.   I look forward to your future postings.